# Set empty string as the value of a key in properties file

Tags: java, security, web-applications, properties, passwords

```
jdbc.password=
```

How can I assign `jdbc.password` key in my application.properties file an empty string?

I understand I can do this programmatically as follows, but I would like to set this in properties file.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("password", "");
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just leaving the value empty on the RHS should be fine:

```
password=
```

Sample code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new StringReader("password="));
        System.out.println(props.size()); // 1
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("password").length()); // 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the test you provided seems to work, the reason behind my question is to set empty password for mysql database connection. When I do this, my jdbc connection fails and gives me the following exception `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection caused by  org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))`

Comment: @Susie: Well that sounds like it's something in the way that the JDBC driver is picking up the properties. I've answered the question you asked - the next thing to do is consult the relevant documentation for how properties are used.

Comment: Also note that if I set mysql password to some string and update the properties file accordingly, my application works fine.

Comment: @Susie: I suggest you ask a *new* question with more details, including the code you're using to configure the JDBC connection.

Comment: I have posted another question here as you suggested:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811182/how-to-set-empty-string-as-password-for-mysql-database-in-properties-file