# How to set empty string as password for MYSQL database in properties file.

Tags: java, database, web-applications, properties, passwords

My question is how do I set empty string as password for mysql database in properties file?

The password for MySql database is an empty string. I tried leaving the right hand side empty like this `jdbc.password=` in my application.properties file but I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Note that if I change of the password of mysql database to some string and update the application.properties file accordingly, my application works fine.

**application.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_app
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
        <context:annotation-config/>

        <!-- view resolver bean definition -->

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
              <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.karmacrafts.model.impl" />
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                 <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                 </props>
              </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
              <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
              <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
              <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
            class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>


        //some other beans
</beans>
```

**DAO file:**

```
@Repository
public class ItemsDao {
        private Session session;
        private Transaction tx;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Item> getAllItems() throws HibernateException{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();        
            List<Item> items = session.createQuery("from Item").list();
            tx.commit();
            return items;
    }
}
```

**Error Stack trace:**

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at com.karmacrafts.model.dao.ItemsDao.getAllItems(ItemsDao.java:55)
    at com.karmacrafts.model.dao.ItemsDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a65cd06b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.karmacrafts.model.dao.ItemsDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8592419d.getAllItems(<generated>)
    at com.karmacrafts.web.controller.ShoppingCartController.viewAllItems(ShoppingCartController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: What happens if you leave jdbc.password out of the properties file completely? Just don't specify it at all?

Comment: @simonatrcl You are correct. But I also had to delete the reference to 'jdbc.password' key in my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. If you can put these two things in your answer and post it, I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just don't specify jdbc.password anywhere!

Cheers -