# How to connect to a jdbc database without password via external driver in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, null, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to connect my Spring Boot application to a database (Transbase) with an external driver I added to the classpath. So far so good but my problem is that the password for the user I'd like to connect to the database is empty.
So I tried to set the application-properties like

```
spring.datasource.password=
```

or dont configure the value at all but I always end up getting the following error:

```
Caused by: transbase.t: 
Transbase JDBC/JDBCX Driver
Release Version 3.0
Build 20150618(490)
Transbase Client Error <30029>:
Invalid property value '<null>' for property 'password'
    at transbase.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[tbjdbc.jar:na]
    at transbase.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source) ~[tbjdbc.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

It seems that the driver can only handle the password when its an empty string but not null. Does anyone know what I need to configure or at least a workaround for this (without changing the db user-password)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set empty string as password for MYSQL database in properties file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811182/how-to-set-empty-string-as-password-for-mysql-database-in-properties-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete 'spring.datasource.password=' line.

if you don't specify its value it is considered empty.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It should also behave as empty with „spring.datasource.password=“ but in both scenarios it doesn‘t.